# Force new local branches to base at specific branch

Tags: git

I have a `git` repo locally with multiple branches, say `develop`, `feat1` and `feat2`. My understanding is that if I am currently on the branch `feat2` and run `git branch feat3`, it will create a new branch `feat3` that has its `HEAD` at `feat2`'s `HEAD`. If I now develop new features on this branch (that is independent from `feat2`) and PR it, it will include the commits of `feat2` too, which is undesirable as I have to rebase or something.

Is there any way to enforce that whenever I type `git branch`, I am always on the `develop` branch? Another potential solution is if I type `git push`, is there a way to check my branch is "based" on `develop`? (I think "based" is not the correct term, please correct me.)

I only want this to happen for this repo, so I believe I have to modify `REPO/.git/*`, but I am not sure what to modify.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just train yourself to type `git branch <newbranch> develop` instead. Or make a `git-newbranch` command that does that for you.

Comment: I do something like `git checkout develop; git pull; git checkout -b feat3`

Comment: @larsks I didn't know that argument even exists. That's definitely an easy habit to pick up :) Thanks so much.

Comment: @erik258 Yes that's what I would do if I remember :)

Comment: I'd skip the checkout as well. `git fetch` followed by `git switch -c feat3 origin/develop --no-track`. (Or `checkout -b` if you prefer.)